# Bootstrap inline form and gutter width

Tags: css, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make my form inline and also trying to reduce the the gutter width between elements in my form. What is the best approach for this?

Here my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssosina/gY3GC/) code and a sample below.

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Put something here">
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
      <select class="form-control dropdown">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3t</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <select class="form-control dropdown">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSFiddle isn't including Bootstrap 3 correctly. Try Bootply.com

Here is the example I made, seems to be working fine http://bootply.com/108144#

In the inline forms the elements need to be wrapped in `class="form-group"`, as far as I can see in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com).

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>Group 1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control">
              <option>Group 2</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </form>
```